# Defining symbols for a contract at compile time - how?

Tags: c++, eosio-cpp

supposing I have a contract declaration in file `t.cpp` as follows:

```
class [[eosio::contract("__CONTRACT__")]] token : public contract {
```

I would expect to be able to compile it like this:

```
$ eosio-cpp -D__CONTRACT__=t t.cpp -o t.wasm --abigen
```

but when I try, I get an empty ABI file.

if I look at what the preprocessor is producing:

```
$ eosio-cpp -D__CONTRACT__=t -E -dD t.cpp  -o - |grep __CONTRACT__
```

it looks right:

```
> #define __CONTRACT__ t
> class [[eosio::contract("__CONTRACT__")]] token : public contract {
```

and I get further confirmation because if I specify the name during compilation everything works just fine:

```
$ eosio-cpp t.cpp -o t.wasm --abigen --contract=__CONTRACT__
```

so are preprocessor symbols just not supported by eosio-cpp as they are in standard C/C++ compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by removing the quotes from `"__CONTRACT__"`.
Anything in quotes is a string literal, and should not get replaced.

If you need the quotes right there, try specifying the quoted string on the right side of the definition, like `#define __CONTRACT__ "t"`.

Comment: ah... quite right.  I guess the preprocessor respects literals.  a million thanks!

Comment: as a side note, the quotes have to be escaped in the call: `-D'__CONTRACT__=\"t\"'`

Comment: you seem good with this stuff: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/529